# Airflow Task execution on multiple celery worker

Tags: celery, celery-task, airflow

I have a airflow installation running with multiple workers using celery executor. I have a dag which has multiple tasks. When I run the dag on this infrastructure each tasks are running in the same worker one by one. I thought airflow will run each tasks is different worker. but it not happening like that. Do we need to explicitly set some configuration.

Comment: This could be a number of things. I’d start with looking at the logs for workers that aren’t picking up tasks. Are there any errors there? Have you touched any of the concurrency related airflow.cfg values or did you set these tasks to run in any specific queue?

Comment: Yes workers picking up the tasks o don't see any error. On my airflow.cfg celery_concurrency is set as 4 and i can see 5 celery process running.

Comment: All workers belongs to same queues